# Log simplification

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

[Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki3PE.jpg)

Now this is the question of asymptotic analysis in Algorithms; My question is $H(n)= n^\frac{1}{\log n}$, First i am taking log of this expression then can I apply power rule here and it will become $\frac{1}{\log n} \log n$ and Here we will have 1 only as answer.

Comment: Use Mathjax to format the mathematics in your questions, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help with the syntax. And try to refrain from using pictures as well, write your question out in full! **Edit:** the post has been edited with the proper Mathjax formatting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image has $\log_2 n$ rather than $\log n$.  If you take $\log_2$ of both sides you have

$$\log_2 H(n) = \frac{1}{\log_2 n}\log_2 n = 1.$$

But that means $H(n) = 2^1 = 2$.  So if you're concluding that $H(n)$ is constant, you're correct.

Comment: Sir, Can you tell me how this 2^1? I don't understand about 2 but you're correct as answer will be 2. Please can you explain in simple language.
Thanks

Comment: My understanding is that first we're taking log therefore now we take 2^1 to balance the equations Right ?

Comment: If $log_a b = c$ then $a^c = b.$